# AWS ECR Login on Win CMD

Tags: cmd, aws-cli, aws-ecr

I am trying to run the AWS CLI login for ECR, however, I haven't succeed in running it properly on Windows CMD. On *nix command is quite simple:

```
$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region <REGION_HERE>)
```

While on windows, I have tried different ways to imitate the subshell behaviour of Linux, but kept on failing.

Anyone knows how to login on AWS CLI with a subshell logic, basically a one-liner which doesnt print out the password and other stuff like the above command on *nix?

Answer (score 2):

This is the windows command, run it in powershell:

```
(Get-ECRLoginCommand).Password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <AccountId>.dkr.ecr.<Region>.amazonaws.com/<ContainerName>
```

You will need to have access keys setup, or an custom solution for MFA (AWS does not provide this)

You might need AWS Powershell tools installed.
https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative without the need to install the AWS Powershell tool is:

```
$env:AWS_REGION = "us-west-2"
$env:AWS_USER = "09E1X6A8MPLE"
$env:AWS_PROFILE = "profile-name"
aws ecr get-login-password --region %AWS_REGION% | 
    docker login --username AWS --password-stdin %AWS_USER%.dkr.ecr.%AWS_REGION%.amazonaws.com
```

[Source](https://techsparx.com/software-development/aws/ecs/use-aws-cli.html)